# Table not being recognized

Tags: python, pandas, tabula, python-camelot

```
import pandas as pd
from tabula import read_pdf
FileName="Filepath"
DF3=read_pdf(FileName,multiple_tables=True,options="--pages 'all'", lattice= True)
print DF3

import pandas as pd
import camelot
FileName="Filepath"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(FileName,pages='1-end')
print tables
```

I am unable to read the tables in PDF files as dataframe using tabula if the tables are spread across multiple pages and the horizontal borders are cut therefore it is not recognized as table. How do I solve this? Can I detect the tables using only vertical lines?

Tried the new package camelot as well but again not able to read the column.

I am able to detect only one table in the sample pdf the 2x2 table is not detected

Sample pdf Link: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=690704CAD1449D85%21105&cid=690704CAD1449D85

Comment: Your link redirects to the blank folder.

Answer (score 0):

So far Camelot has no implementation of merging Multi-page Tables. My Suggestion would be to Extract the tables as a dataframe and manually merge them with pd.concat.

You can also try out Tabula instead.